# Scraping stock names from Chartink screener

Tags: python, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape available list of stocks from a chartink screener, at any given time.

Example screener: https://chartink.com/screener/15-minute-stock-breakouts

The Inspect element option shows me stock names in between HTML tags (between 'td' and 'tr').
But when I print the output on Python page, stock names are missing (nothing available between 'td' and 'tr').
Leads me to suspect whether Chartink site is scraping-proof. Or maybe it's my limited knowledge.

Can you please give it a shot, and advise. And if not Python, would I be able to get the stock list via any other tool (like VBA)? I am using Microsoft Edge on Windows 11.

Below is the code. As you would see I have tried different things, but failed.

```
import pandas as pd
# from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import numpy as np
import schedule
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://chartink.com/screener/15-minute-stock-breakouts")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
print(soup)

# url = 'https://chartink.com/screener/15-minute-stock-breakouts'
# driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\Users\kashk\Downloads\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe')
# driver.get(url)
# pd.read_html(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]').get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically and is retrieved from a XHR so if you are using Selenium, you probably have to wait for the data to be loaded first.

Below method uses XMLHTTP approach and seems to work for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Chartink()
    Dim reqObj As Object
    Set reqObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    With reqObj
        .Open "GET", "https://chartink.com/screener/15-minute-stock-breakouts", False
        .Send
        
        Dim reqDoc As Object
        Set reqDoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        reqDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        
        'Retrieve the CSRF token that is required for XHR later
        Dim metaEle As Object
        Set metaEle = reqDoc.getElementsByName("csrf-token")(0)
    
        'Retrieve the JSON data
        .Open "POST", "https://chartink.com/screener/process", False
        .setRequestHeader "x-csrf-token", metaEle.Content
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .Send "scan_clause=(+%7B57960%7D+(+%5B0%5D+15+minute+close+%3E+%5B-1%5D+15+minute+max(+20+%2C+%5B0%5D+15+minute+close+)+and+%5B0%5D+15+minute+volume+%3E+%5B0%5D+15+minute+sma(+volume%2C20+)+)+)+"
                
        Dim resultDict As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set resultDict = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To resultDict("data").Count
            Debug.Print resultDict("data")(i)("name") & vbTab & resultDict("data")(i)("close") & vbTab & resultDict("data")(i)("volume")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

You will need [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) and reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` for the `JsonConverter.ParseJson` method.

Comment: Thanks, runs like a charm, and obviously much above my expertise. But may I ask, where does the output get printed? Did not see a pop-up or file created, after the program runs.

Comment: Please excuse my question. I get it now. You did say, data is loaded dynamically. Once Chartink screener starts running dynamically, I do get pop-ups from this macro. Thanks a ton !

Comment: @Kashyap the output is `Debug.Print`/printed in the Immediate Window (Press Ctrl-G to open it in the VBE) in my answer code. You have to modify the output to suit your purpose.

Comment: @Kashyap If this answer address/resolves your question, please click the tick icon beside the answer to accept it.

Comment: Oops so sorry Raymond, I see it now. Thanks so much. I lament me being out of touch with VBA. It should have been obvious to me